# C# how to check the string in a textbox is what you want it to be

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, textbox, equals

making a rock paper scissors game in C# for college. 
I want to show  message box when the player enters an invalid command (not rock, paper or scissors) . I tryed this but cant get it to work..

```
        //if player enters wrong command they will 
        //this feedback
        if (textBoxAttack.Text != "rock" || textBoxAttack.Text != "rock" || textBoxAttack.Text != "paper" || textBoxAttack.Text != "Paper" || textBoxAttack.Text != "scissors" || textBoxAttack.Text != "Scissors")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not a valid attack"
                           + "\nPlease Enter one of the Following:"
                           + "\nrock"
                           + "\npaper"
                           + "\nscissors");
            textBoxAttack.Text = "";
        }
```

It works if i just type in one command (eg: if (textBoxAttack.Text != "rock") )

any pointers? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered other types of input for this? Radio buttons, drop downs?

Comment: While I prefer Selman's suggestion of using an array (`string[]`), the actual problem with your logic is using the logical OR (`||`) operator instead of the logical AND (`&&`) operator.

Comment: Just think about the if-statement for a moment. How should that ever evaluate to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boolean logic is wrong, because it will always not equal to one of the values, and thus will always be true.  Change `||` to `&&`, and it should work.

Answer (score 5):

You need `&&` instead of `||`.

However, i would prefer this concise and readable approach:

```
string[] allowed = { "rock", "paper", "scissors" };
if (!allowed.Contains(textBoxAttack.Text, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{ 
    string msg = string.Format("Not a valid attack{0}Please Enter one of the Following:{0}{1}"
        , Environment.NewLine, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allowed));
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
    textBoxAttack.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `array`, it makes your work easier.Also you can use `ToLower` method to make a *case-insensitive* check.

```
var values = new [] { "rock", "paper", "scissors" };

if(!values.Contains(textBoxAttack.Text.ToLower()) 
{
    // invalid value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = textBoxAttack.Text.ToLowerInvariant();
if (text.Text != "rock" && text.Text != "paper" && text.Text != "scissors")
{
...
}
```

Use a dropdownlist/radiobuttons instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (textBoxAttack.Text == "rock" || textBoxAttack.Text == "Paper" || textBoxAttack.Text == "Scissors")
{
//..Do What do you want
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Not a valid attack"
                           + "\nPlease Enter one of the Following:"
                           + "\nrock"
                           + "\npaper"
                           + "\nscissors");
            textBoxAttack.Text = "";
}
```

Use Combo Box or 3 Buttons for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the same but for example adding ToLower() at the end of each text attribute. This way you will only need to check 3 (rock, paper or scissors) becauuse the iput will be lower case ;)

And for the messageBox try something like this:

```
string[] message = { "Not a valid attack", "Please Enter one of the Following:", "rock", "paper", "scissors" };

if (textBoxAttack.Text.ToLower() != "rock" && textBoxAttack.Text.ToLower() != "paper" && textBoxAttack.Text.ToLower() != "scissors")
    {
       MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", message));
       textBoxAttack.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: Oh damn ahaha I thought that I was reading == and not != xD noob mistake by my side! ;) Thanks David! ;)

Comment: Fix your answer and I'll remove the downvote. I don't downvote much but when the answer is wrong it's a good reason. Then I'll delete my comments, too, so no one will ever know this happened. :)

Comment: Dont need to remove the comments ;) A mistake is a mistake ;) I have learnt a lot with this David! Thanks

Comment: Oscar you seem like nice and honorable guy. One of the cool features on StackOverflow is that you can edit your answers and even delete them. A mistake might be a mistake but that doesn't mean you can't fix it - in fact, you're encouraged to so so and in that event removing a downvote would be the correct thing. And we all do it - I've posted answers that were so far off base sometimes and got 3 downvotes that it was easier to just delete them than fix the problem. No need to be hard on yourself dude!

Comment: The answer is already fixed, but the downvote remember me that I need to check my answers and the questions more carefully! ;) It´s the only way to learn.. to make mistakes! But if we delete the mistakes... we can´t learn from them!